# initwithframe reuseidentifier deprecated

Tags: ios

Can anyone help with this error I'm having with 5.0:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

[`-initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW32) is deprecated. You want to use [`-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW2) instead.

Comment: Would you mind posting the full code I should use as I get another error

Comment: @MylesKaye: What error? It's really rather simple. `[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]`.

Comment: CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60);
-
-
Error:
Unused Variable 'CellFrame'

Comment: @MylesKaye: Why are you declaring a variable you don't need?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `initWithStyle: reuseIdentifier:`.
 `initWithFrame: reuseIdentifier:` may become illegal in iOS 6a nd your app won't work.

Comment: Can you edit the code I originally posted with the correction I should use, I get another error :(

Answer (score 0):

I thought Kevin was very clear in his explanation.

Use:
`UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];`

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, so your `CellFrame` is still used
Use:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
cell.frame = CellFrame; // setting your frame you used before;
```